# Military and Business Strategy

Tags: competition, political

I am thinking through the parallels between military and business strategy but am stuck on a foundational aspect. Most of business strategy results from some kind of competition in order to gain market share, which can be measured by revenue, profit, or the amount of benefit/utility a consumer gains from the product or service. However I am struggling with creating an analogy for the measure or benefits from military competition. Is there a similar way to describe "security" or policy attainment as a result of a military competition (battle/war)? I have reviewed the game theory ideas around military conflicts, and don't believe this is the correct approach, but will be glad to consider a different perspective. Thank you

Comment: Haven't read this but looks relevant: "[This article](https://jpe.pm-research.com/content/8/3/7.abstract) provides a review of this literature and concludes that, if indeed the theory of cooperative games is a proper paradigm for business, then the military leader is not the appropriate role model."

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/oep/article-abstract/66/3/721/2364619) on conflict minerals could be of aid as well.